# When I add a column with checkboxes, I cannot see them?

Tags: list-view, column

I want to add check boxes but when I try it, it does not seem.

I followed and tried these steps and it does not solve my problem.Still, there is empty.

1. Select the All Document view dropdown at the end of the bread crumb.  Then   “Modify this view”.
2. In the view, scroll down to Tabular View and make sure it is checked.
   Still, in the view, scroll down to the Style setting.  When you open up the Style setting you will see “Default” view selected.  Select any other view.
3. Select OK button at the bottom of the Modify View Panel
4. Now reselect the Modify View at the end of the bread crumb (i.e., go back in       to change the style back)
5. Scroll down to the Style setting and reselect the Default view again.
   Select OK button at the bottom
6. Display the view.  You should see the select boxes.

Comment: what do you mean with column with checkboxes?